# How to handle Mazovia encoded text

Tags: java, text, encoding

Im using Java to edit some text files containing records. Those files are handled by old systems that most **probably** use Mazovia ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazovia_encoding)) encoding. I cant find a way to handle the files properly and it's beginning to give me a headache.

When I edit the text files with my Java code, the systems find additional characters in them, breaking the entire record structure (character position matters).

How do I edit those files without introducing any additional characters/breaking the encoding?  Proper display of all characters would be great, but if it's not possible, I'll make do with simply not breaking the record structure.

Comment: Not sure what "Mazovia" means here - would it match any of the ISO-8859 variants? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859

Comment: The encoding might be "Cp437" (DOS). `byte[] bytes = ...; new String(bytes. "Cp437");`

Answer (score 1):

If you use for example ISO-8859-1 when reading and writing you will not break the file since every byte maps to a character and every character maps to a single byte. (Any encoding with these characteristics will do.)

You won't get the correct Unicode characters when reading (for that you would have to implement a custom `Charset` and I'm not sure how much work that is), but at least you won't break the file.